# Local variable not initializing in C#

Tags: c#, linq, caching, memory, initialization

I have a static function that initializes a list of tiles:

```
private static bool MyFunction(SomeObj obj) 
{
    List<Tile> tiles = obj.Tile.GetTilesBetween(otherTile);
    
    // do stuff
}
```

Later in MyFunction(), I initialize a collection using LINQ:

```
{
    // we did stuff

    List<Commands> commands = CommandsOccuringInTimespan(obj.timeElapsed);
    IEnumerable<Commands> match = commands.Where(c => tiles.Contains(c.End));

    // do more stuff
}
```

However, the presence of these lines, specifically the initialization of `match`, is causing `tiles` to either not initialize or to initialize but not be available in the Debugger. I can't understand why this would be happening.

I can seem to make it work if I make a copy of `tiles` and use that when initializing match:

```
    // we did stuff

    List<Commands> commands = CommandsOccuringInTimespan(obj.timeElapsed);
    List<Tile> copyOfTiles = new List<Tile>(tiles);
    IEnumerable<Commands> match = commands.Where(c => copyOfTiles.Contains(c.End));

    // do more stuff
}
```

C# 7 (I think; this is a Unity3D app so I believe that's the current supported version).

Comment: You declare `tiles` in `MyFunction` so that is the only place you can access it - it doesnt exist elsewhere.  Read about *variable scope*

Comment: I am accessing it in `MyFunction()`. The issue is not that `tiles` does not exist, the issue is that using it when initializing `match` affects `tiles` in some fashion that I do not understand.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "either not initialize or to initialize but not be available in the Debugger"?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] and [edit] that into your question. As it is now, it's only confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the .ToList() method to tiles:

```
List<Tile> tiles = obj.Tile.GetTilesBetween(otherTile).ToList();
```

Comment: GetTilesBetween() is a method that returns a list. I tried it just to see but it didn't make a difference (nor did I expect it to).